# SpringXD - Error in Gemfire as sink

Tags: spring, spring-xd, gemfire, geode

I am trying to setup a stream in springXD.

gemfire is installed in 10.99.40.60 machine and springXD is installed in my LOCAL VM.

```
        xd:>stream create --name gemfiredemo --definition "http --port=9090 | gemfire-server --host=10.99.40.60--port=10334 --useLocator=true   
    --regionName=region --keyExpression=payload.getField('symbol')" --deploy   

Created and deployed new stream 'gemfiredemo'
```

I am running spring XD in my local VM machine...

While posting any data from VM:

```
    xd:>http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data {"symbol":"ORCL","price":38}
    > POST (text/plain;Charset=UTF-8) http://localhost:9090 {"symbol":"ORCL","price":38}
    > 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    > 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR  
Error sending data '{"symbol":"ORCL","price":38}' to 'http://localhost:9090'
```

The actual error log shows:

```
[info 2015/12/07 09:27:49.633 UTC  <poolTimer-client-pool-88> tid=0x13e] Unable to prefill pool to minimum because: com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.NoAvailableLocatorsException: Unable to connect to any locators in the list [machine60:10334, 10.99.40.60/10.99.40.60:10334]

[info 2015/12/07 09:27:49.644 UTC  <poolTimer-client-pool-118> tid=0x13f] Unable to prefill pool to minimum because: com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.NoAvailableLocatorsException: Unable to connect to any locators in the list [liacm218:10334, 10.99.40.60/10.99.40.60:10334]
2015-12-07 09:27:53,427 1.1.2.RELEASE ERROR pool-14-thread-26 http.NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter - Error sending message
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method getField(java.lang.String) cannot be found on java.lang.String type
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:107)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:87)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.monitorSend(DirectChannelMetrics.java:114)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.doInvoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:98)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.invoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.send(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.monitorSend(DirectChannelMetrics.java:114)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.doInvoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:98)
        at org.springframework.integration.monitor.DirectChannelMetrics.invoke(DirectChannelMetrics.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.send(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.x.http.NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter.access$800(NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter.java:86)
        at org.springframework.integration.x.http.NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter$Handler.messageReceived(NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter.java:319)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.doRun(ChannelUpstreamEventRunnable.java:43)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:67)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor$ChildExecutor.run(OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method getField(java.lang.String) cannot be found on java.lang.String type
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:211)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:125)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:153)
        at org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler.parseCacheEntries(CacheWritingMessageHandler.java:93)
        at org.springframework.integration.gemfire.outbound.CacheWritingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(CacheWritingMessageHandler.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what payload type you are expecting for this...

```
--keyExpression=payload.getField('symbol')
```

but, if you add

```
--inputType='application/x-java-object;type=java.util.HashMap'
```

to your sink definition and add

```
--contentType application/json
```

to your `http post` request, you can then use

```
--keyExpression=payload.symbol
```

The runtime will automatically convert the json to a map for you.

Comment: Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Error with option(s) for module gemfire-server of type sink:
    contentType: option named 'contentType' is not supported

Comment: I think you mis-read my answer, or mis-understood. The `contentType` is set when you POST your HTTP request, not in the stream definition.